# How to upload images from iPhone app developed using Titanium

Tags: php, image, iphone-sdk-3.0, titanium

I finally landed up in developing an iPhone app using Titanium Mobile. Now the problem I face is, Im able to run the app, and the app also sends the image to the server. But Im not able to see the file that got uploaded to the server. I have pasted the iPhone app's code to send image to the server and also, the PHP file that would receive the file from the app.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var ind=Titanium.UI.createProgressBar({
width:200,
height:50,
min:0,
max:1,
value:0,
style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
top:10,
message:'Uploading Image',
font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
color:'#888'
});

win.add(ind);
ind.show();

Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({

success:function(event)
{
    Ti.API.info("success! event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    var image = event.media;

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.onerror = function(e)
    {
        Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
    };
    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        Ti.API.info('IN ONLOAD ' + this.status + ' readyState ' + this.readyState);
    };
    xhr.onsendstream = function(e)
    {
        ind.value = e.progress ;
        Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress+' '+this.status+' '+this.readyState);
    };
    // open the client
    xhr.open('POST','http://www.myserver.com/tmp/upload2.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    // send the data
    xhr.send({media:image});

},
cancel:function()
{

},
error:function(error)
{
},
allowImageEditing:true
});
```

And here is the PHP code on the server: http://www.pastie.org/891050

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Please help me out in this issue. Would love to provide if you need some more information.

Answer (score 2):

use following code for Php:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path .  $_FILES['media']['name']; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['media']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks! And Now it works fine! But Im not able to get the file with extension! As in, the iPhone uploads the images without any unique name or extension!