# Upload(Browse) image/video files on webview

Tags: android, iphone, image, file-upload, titanium

We have webview in titanium mobile application, that is displaying remote HTML with some input text fields and button of attache files. The button is not functioning in webview whether same webpage is working fine on Android browser for attaching files.

As I need to upload some information in text fields with image/video files so it is hard to upload file natively.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. On iOS you don't have access to the filesystem. Therefore you will have to do it natively by accessing the albums.

Also look here: [How to upload images from iPhone app developed using Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532478/how-to-upload-images-from-iphone-app-developed-using-titanium)

Comment: Thanks for responding properly. As the HTML is dynamic and remote on webview, so it is hard to implement natively.Do you have any Idea about Android.

Comment: sorry I don't know about android, but I think it's exactly the same. Uploading files from mobile phones is hard!